# What are best practices for modular C development

Tags: c, git, code-organization

I am in the middle of programming something in C.

I have this:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/MemHashMapC

and this:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/asyncore

I want first repository to uses the second.

Alternatively I may have third repository that uses both these.

I know I can do it with "ar", but since both repositories are mine, probably there are better way?

Is there any best practices for modular development like this in C?

I am using Linux and gcc.

Comment: You didn't really ask a question...

Comment: Thanks. I made changes in the question. Hope now is clear. (if I knew how to formulate the question, I would use Google)

Comment: This has nothing (specific) to do with C - that just happens to be the language you're using but you would face the same question with any other language.

Comment: you are not right. most of other languages have package managers - npm for node, composer for php, package and JAR organisation for java, there even are some stuff in progress for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution for structure:
You could identify and separate the components of the software in folders. After this you could create folders for each project (containing the Makefile) which will use the components created.

To use one repo in another repo you could try using git submodule: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule .